# Http Post request in Angular JS

Tags: ajax, angularjs

We are new to angular js.

We tried http request using `$http.get` it is working fine. But in post request it is creating an issue, it comes to success and show bad parameter error code 103.

Same we have tried in ajax request using `$.ajax({}),` and it is working fine.

I have also paste my code.

Can anyone help us out?

```
mainApp.controller('registrationCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http) {
    $scope.registration = function() {
        console.log("registration called");
        var ws_url = "http://apparelinindia.com/selfiestandoff/WebServices/register";

        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: ws_url,
            data: {
                user_email: $scope.email,
                user_password: $scope.password
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }

        });
        request.success(function(data) {
            console.log("Success" + data);
        });
        request.error(function(error) {
            console.log("Success" + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Tried with `method: "POST"` instead?

Comment: And remove `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use http Post in following way:

```
  var request = $http.post(ws_url, {
        user_email: $scope.email,
        user_password: $scope.password
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the http method should be written in uppercase. Also, the property `datatype` is not awaited by `$http`, you should remove it:

```
var request = $http({
     method: "POST",
     url: ws_url,
     data: {
         user_email: $scope.email,
         user_password: $scope.password
     },
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
});
```

Note, in the above call to `$http` you are setting the header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`. But this header is automatically injected by `$http` (**see [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)**), therefore you can remove it, and use the short syntax:

```
var request = $http.post(ws_url, data);
```

with `data` equals to:

```
{
    user_email: $scope.email,
    user_password: $scope.password
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You Getting this error  ??

```
{"status":false,"error":{"code":"103","message":"Required Parameters not found"}}
```

If Yes, Its Not your Problem Contact the Web service provider.

Ask him to give the valid parameter